# What is the difference between ; and GO in stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

What is the difference between `;` and `GO` in stored procedure in SQL Server ?

Actually, if I have a stored procedure in SQL server and wanna to put t separate queries inside it which the first one just calculates number of records (count) and the second one selects some records based on some conditions, then what should I use between that two queries?

`Go` or `;`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`;` just ends the statement.

GO is not a statement but a command to the server to commit the current batch to the Database. It creates a stop inside the transaction.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

(Update, thanks for the comments):
GO is a statement intended for the Management studio as far as I know, maybe to other tools as well.

Comment: Actually, go is redundant outside "management studio". I wont (-1) though.

Comment: Try executing a statement with `GO` in it through a SqlCommand, it will throw an exception.

Comment: Exactly, it's a command to the client tool (SSMS, osql, sqlcmd, etc), not to the server. And in some of these tools, the command can be defined as some other sequence. Though if anyone does this, I implicitly hate them and all the scripts they create. :-|

Comment: yes the go is the command to the intermediate query client tools that manipulate it

Answer (score 20):

The semicolon separates queries, the GO command separates batches. (Also GO is not a T-SQL command, it's a command recognised by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and Management Studio.)

You can't use GO inside a stored procedure. If you would try, the definition of the procedure will end there, and the rest will be a separate batch.

A local variable has the scope of the batch, so after a GO command you can't use local variables declared before the GO command:

```
declare @test int

set @test = 42

GO

select @Test -- causes an error message as @Test is undefined
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this thread is old but I thought these other uses/differences might be handy for other searches like myself regarding `GO`.

1. Anything after the `GO` will not wind up in your sproc because the `GO` will execute the `CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE` command. For example, if you run this...

   CREATE PROCEDURE X AS
   SELECT 1 As X
   GO
   SELECT 2 As X

Then after running it you go back in to edit the procedure you will find that only the `SELECT 1 As X` is in there because the `GO` created the sproc and anything after it is assumed to be the next thing you are doing and not part of the sproc.

2. I'm surprised I haven't seen this mentioned much out there but the batch separator is not only specific to the program you are querying with but in the case of SSMS it is actually user editable! If I went into the settings and changed the batch separator from GO to XX then in my copy of SSMS, XX executes the batch not GO. So what would happen if I tried to execute a stored procedure that contained GO?

Think of `GO` as a way of telling SSMS to send whatever is above it to the server for execution. The server never receives the `GO` as that is just there to mark the end of a batch of command you want SSMS to send to the server.
If you have a scenario where you need to control execution flow in your stored procedure then you can use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` for that and those are allowed in stored procedures.

Answer (score 4):

GO is not a command to the server, it's the default batch separator for most of the client tools the MS supply. When the client tool encounters "GO" on a new line by itself, it sends whatever commands it has accumulated thus far to the server, and then starts over anew.

What this means is that any variables declared in one batch are not available in subsequent batches. And it also means that multi-line comments can't be placed around a "GO" command - because the server will see the first batch, and see an unterminated comment.

Answer (score 2):

It marks the end of a batch in Query Analyzer and
therefore signals the end of a stored procedure definition in that batch.
As much as i know its not a part of sp.
GO isn't a TSQL command.

And ; just ends the statement.