# Please help me fix this stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

When I try to create the following stored procedure, I get this error message:
what am I doing wrong?

```
Create  Procedure uspUpdateWithNewSSN
    (
      @OldSSN VARCHAR(9)
      ,@NewSSN VARCHAR(9)
     )
       AS 
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 BEGIN
If OBJECT_ID(N'NewSSNEXIST') IS NULL
   Begin
    Create Table NewSSNEXIST
    (
       NewSSN nvarchar(9)NOT NULL   
    )
  End

 Begin
    Insert into  NewSSNEXIST
    Exec uspCheckNewSSN @NewSSN
    GO
 End

If (select count(*) from NewSSNEXIST)>0
Begin 
    print 'social security number already used'
    Truncate Table NewSSNEXIST;
    Return
End
Else
 --Begin update ssn 
Begin
--Declare @OldSSN VARCHAR(9)
--Declare @NewSSN VARCHAR(9)
Declare @cmd   VARCHAR(MAX)
--Set @OldSSN='222334444'
--Set @NewSSN='222334644'

 Select @cmd =  COALESCE(@cmd,'') +
'
    UPDATE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] SET [' + Column_Name + '] = ' + @NewSSN + '  
    WHERE [' + Column_Name + '] = ' + @OldSSN + '
 '

From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
Where Column_Name like 'SSN%'       
OR Column_Name LIKE 'ssn%'          
OR Column_Name LIKE 'ssn%'          
OR Column_Name LIKE '%_ssn%'            
OR Column_Name LIKE '_ocsecno'          
OR Column_Name LIKE 'Ssn%';

--Select @cmd
EXEC(@cmd)
End
    END

      GO
```

Comment: You can't use `GO` in a stored procedure: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/2310488/1115360](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2310488/1115360).

Comment: you have a Batch separator `GO` in your code

Comment: Please do yourself and your company favor and "fix" this procedure by redesigning how you store this information. SSN should NEVER be stored as plain text. Not encrypting this data is negligent.

Comment: I agree with you sean. I inherited a poorly designed database. I don't even know where to start from to fix it.

Comment: I will add to what Sean Lange said. It is not just data negligent but not encrypting ssns and dobs et al may actually be illegal. It will most certainly open yourself and or your company to a boat load of lawsuits if the data gets out.

Comment: Also you may have a sql injection vector where you are doing your concatenation. The "SET NOCOUNT ON" should be after the begin.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `GO` key word in your procedure you should also look into your dynamic sql and fix it as follows

```
Declare @cmd   VARCHAR(MAX)

 Select @cmd = N' UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) 
            +  N' SET  ' + QUOTENAME(c.name)   + N' =  @NewSSN   '
            +  N' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(c.name)  + N' =  @OldSSN  '

From sys.tables t 
Inner join sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
Inner join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
Where c.name like 'SSN%'       
OR c.name LIKE 'ssn%'          
OR c.name LIKE 'ssn%'          
OR c.name LIKE '%_ssn%'            
OR c.name LIKE '_ocsecno'          
OR c.name LIKE 'Ssn%';

--Select @cmd
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd
                  ,N' @OldSSN VARCHAR(9) ,@NewSSN VARCHAR(9)'
                  ,@OldSSN
                  ,@NewSSN
```